# How to increment a number inside <p> in html upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I increment a number in `p` tag in HTML upon click on a picture? The code that I have tried seems to be not working.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".minusbutton", function() {
  $('.parquantity').html(parseInt($('.parquantity').html(), 10) + 1)
  alert('you clicked on button #');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amountCounter">
  <img class="minusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/minus.png" alt="minus">
  <div class="quantity">
    <p class="parquantity">1</p>
  </div>
  <img class="plusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/plus.png" alt="plus">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, attach the click event to both images then you could use `text()` instead of `html()` since you deal with the text value (you need no HTML tags).

You could use `++/--` to add/subtract one when you click :

```js
$(document).on("click", ".plusbutton", function() {
  var parquantity = parseInt($('.parquantity').text(), 10);
  $('.parquantity').text(++parquantity);
});

$(document).on("click", ".minusbutton", function() {
  var parquantity = parseInt($('.parquantity').text(), 10) - 1;

  if (parquantity > 0) {
    $('.parquantity').text(parquantity);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amountCounter">
  <img class="minusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/minus.png" alt="minus">
  <div class="quantity">
    <p class="parquantity">1</p>
  </div>
  <img class="plusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/plus.png" alt="plus">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, so it is .text() that does the trick thank you very much

Comment: i am trying to put a limiter on how low the number can get but it disables the button entirely `$(document).on("click", ".minusbutton", function() {
                var parquantity = parseInt($('.parquantity').text(), 10);
                --parquantity;
                if(parquantity==0)
                parquantity=1;
                $('.parquantity').text(parquality);
              })` isnt this like javascript where i can just free use the variables?

Comment: Thank you very much. can i ask why my code will not work? does that mean i cannot do normal js stuff?

Comment: Sure you can, your code will work it has just a typo in `$('.parquantity').text(parquality)` note the name of vaiable must be `parquantity` not `parquality`

Comment: oh that is really embarrassing ,  thank you very much !

Comment: No worries, that happen to all of us

Answer (score 2):

You can increase and decrease target number in one event listener. Also using [`.text( fucntion )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) the code is simpler

```js
$(document).on("click", ".minusbutton, .plusbutton", function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  $('.parquantity').text(function(i, t){
    return ele.is(".plusbutton") ? +t+1 : +t-1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amountCounter">
  <img class="minusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/minus.png" alt="minus">
  <div class="quantity">
    <p class="parquantity">1</p>
  </div>
  <img class="plusbutton" src="/mcdb/Logos/plus.png" alt="plus">
</div>
```